# Do I need FileDescriptor "sync" and MappedByteBuffer "force"?

Tags: java, nio, memory-mapped-files

When I want to make sure that the changes of a MappedByteBuffer should be synced back to disc do I need `randomAcccessFile.getFD().sync()` or `mappedByteBuffer.force()` or both? (In my simple tests none of them seems to be required - confusing ...)

Somebody has an idea about the actual underlying operations or at least could explain the differences if any?

Comment: "Better safe than sorry"? ;)

Comment: Well, yes I could do just both but additionally I would like to understand the differences or the underlying operations :). updated question

Comment: Hmmh, when I look at the javadocs of filechannel.map they say "A mapping, once established, is not dependent upon the file channel that was used to create it. " so getFD.sync should do nothing important!?

Comment: Well, the underlying native operations are very different. FOr instance, on Unix-like systems, I suspect a `MappedByteBuffer` uses `mmap()` and so the semantics of `mmap()` apply. On Windows there is no `mmap()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, FileDescriptor.sync is equivalent to FileChannel.force (calling the POSIX fsync method)

Second, in the Book "Java NIO" from Ron Hitchens (via [google books](http://www.google.de/search?tbm=bks&q=java%20nio)) in the chapter about MappedByteBuffer it says

> MappedByteBuffer.force() is similar to the method of the same name in the FileChannel class. It forces any changes made to the mapped buffer to be flushed out to permanent disc storage. When updating a file through MappedByteBuffer object, you should always use MappedByteBuffer.force() rather than FileChannel.force(). The channel object may not be aware of all file updates made through the mapped buffer. MappedByteBuffer doesn't give you the option of not flushing file metadata - it's always flushed too. Note, that the same considerations regarding nonlocal filesystems apply here as they do for FileChannel.force

So, yes. You need to call MappedByteBuffer.force!

BUT then I found [this bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6816049) which indicates that both calls could be still necessary at least on Windows.

Comment: That bug page says it has been fixed for Java 7.